# return value of a function in C when it does not return any value

Tags: c, return-value

What does a function in C return when it does not have any return value?

For example this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
f1(void);
f2(void);

main()
{
  x=10;
  printf("x = %d, ",x);
  printf("x = %d, ",f1());
  printf("x = %d, ",f2());
}   

f1(void)
{
}  

f2(void)
{
}
```

Comment: Use `void` as return type, if the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Don't forget to turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: sorry mahesh: but i wouldn't be able to explain the solution you give to my examiner.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't legal C any more, but `f1` and `f2` are implicitly returning `int`, so you're just getting random values returned, likely based on what happened to be at the top of the stack.

Comment: every time u run this program it will give u the same output, but I am not able to understand why ..

Comment: There is no reason in C why it should, because it is undefined behavior according to C. Look at the assembly your compiler is generating if you really want to know what's happening in your specific case.

Answer (score 3):

Any function without a declared type is assumed to return `int` in older versions of C, but you do not want to rely on this behaviour. (Plus, you'll normally get a warning for this).

Because the functions don't `return` anything, but are implicitly declared to return `int`, your program exhibits **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: but nneonneo every time I run this program its giving me same output, but I am not able to understand why ...

Comment: @AbhilashGoyal: Blame undefined behaviour. Compiler might output code such that the return register always happens to hold the same value, but if you change something (code in the function, optimization settings, compiler version), it may suddenly change. Don't **ever** rely on undefined behaviour to be consistent.

Comment: There's really not much utility in trying to understand undefined behavior, just avoid it.

Comment: @AbhilashGoyal "Undefined behavior" doesn't mean that the output would be random each time you run the compiled program or that the compiler would create a different program every time you compile the code. Most of the time it means that the behavior is (or could be) different in *different compilers* or with different compiler settings.

Comment: Paul: actually this question was asked today in our viva ... I am not able to get proper explanation of this ...

Comment: You've just been given a proper explanation.